# Have an ISession in ASP.NET MVC (not .NET Core) to support Dependency Injection / Scalability

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've inherited an Asp.Net MVC 5 application which makes largely use of `Session["XXX"]` to store everything (and with everything, I mean everything...)

Now since I'm performing a lot of refactoring and my desiderata is to move sessions to Redis (There 3 different application server with a load balancer and in order to make things working Sticky Session are used) my first step was to introduce a ISession interface with and start replacing all those `Item item = (Item)Session["Item"];` with `ISession.Get<T>("Item")`

In my previous working place, we used ServiceStack and their implementation was awesome, the Interface was clear

```
 public interface ISession
{
    object this[string key] { get; set; }

    void Set<T>(string key, T value);

    T Get<T>(string key);

    bool Remove(string key);

    void RemoveAll();
}
```

And I wish to implement something similar. My problem is that the Session item is defined inside Controller class as

```
  public HttpSessionStateBase Session
{
  get
  {
    if (this.HttpContext != null)
      return this.HttpContext.Session;
    return (HttpSessionStateBase) null;
  }
}
```

Is there a way I can have a SessionService which makes use of the HttpContext.Current.Session?

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you just need a shim class that maps `ISession.Get<T>("Item")` calls to `(Item)Session["Item"]`.

Comment: I don't want just to have an extension method around Session["XXX"] , I wish to centralize all the access of the session in a single point, so that if tomorrow I'll have to move to Redis I'll have just a little bit of manteinance

Comment: That's what the shim is for.  I'm not talking about extension methods; I'm talking about the *adapter pattern.*